# Groupby from relation laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I simply want to sum the column quantity_ton from actual_discharging model and groupby cargo_type from schedule_loading

```
data: 
[{
   "actual_discharging":{
       "id": "2",
       "quantity_ton": "44",
       "actual_loading": {},
       "schedule_loading": {
           "id": "40",
           "vessel_type": "001 - Spot Contract",
           "destination": "002 - Export",
           "cargo_type": "004 - Container"
       }
    }

}]
```

i've tried to use whereHas but it is not working

```
        $data = $data->select(DB::raw("SUM(quantity_ton) as total"))->whereHas('schedule_loading',function($query){
        $query->groupBy('cargo_type');
    })->get();
```

also tried this code but it's also not working

[image]

this is the model and relationship

```
class ActualDischarging extends Model
{
    use Compoships;
    protected $table = "actual_discharging";

    protected $fillable = [
        'vessel','voyage_no','discharging_port','actual_arrival','actual_berthing','actual_discharging_from','actual_discharging_to','actual_departure','cement_type','packing','pack_kind','quantity_bag','quantity_ton','n_of_containers','shrinkage','shortage','overlanded','claim_rate','returning_port','actual_return_arrival'
    ];

    public function schedule_loading(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\ScheduleLoading',['vessel','voyage_no','cement_type','packing','pack_kind'],['vessel','voyage_no','cement_type','packing','pack_kind']);
    }
}
```

how do i make the output display objects with the name of cargo_type and its sum?

Comment: plz post your migration and relationship.

Comment: relationship aded

Comment: Try moving your `->whereHas` closure to the `->with()` I believe that's what you're looking for

Comment: @Azeame like this?
        $data = ActualDischarging::with(['actual_loading','schedule_loading'])->whereHas('schedule_loading',function($query){
            $query->groupBy('cargo_type');
        })->get();
no this is not what i wanted but thanks, i just wanted to display objects that says it's cargo_type and sum

Comment: No, like this ActualDischarging::with(['actual_loading','schedule_loading'=>function($query){ $query->groupBy('cargo_type'); }])

Comment: @Azeame tried it but that's not what i want, my data has many records with many cargo_type from schedule_loading and i just want to sum quantity_ton from actual_discharging then groupBy cargo_type from schedule_loading